# How to solve 'cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘cv::DescriptorExtractor*’ in initialization'?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [bigg_detector](http://ros.org/wiki/bigg_detector).

```
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector$ rosmake
  [ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                                                                                
  [ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['bigg_detector']                                                                                  
  [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['bigg_detector']                                                                                          
  [ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121008-104935                                                         
  [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['bigg_detector'] to:
  ['bigg_detector']                                                                              
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                                                                                     
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                                                                       
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                                                                   
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                                                      
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                                                                                 
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                                                                                         
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole                                                                         
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild                                                                             
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                                                                               
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                                                                                       
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                                                       
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib                                                                                  
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                                                                                 
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond                                                                                      
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                                                                                        
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib                                                                            
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]                                                                                                      
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                                                                                      
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                                                                                   
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp                                                                                
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice                                                                         
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2                                                                                
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                                                                                      
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                                                                                          
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs                                                                   
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                                                                                       
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                  
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure                                                        
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet                                                                                
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs                                                                       
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                                                                                       
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                                                                                      
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                                                                                  
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                                                                                       
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                                                                                              
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                                                                                  
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                                                                                       
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters                                                               
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                     
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf                                                                                 
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                                                                               
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs                                                                             
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosbag  No Makefile in package rosbag                                                                                 
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                                                                                          
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                                                                                           
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> image_geometry [ make ]                                                                                               
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]                                                                                               
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools                                                        
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< image_geometry ROS_NOBUILD in package image_geometry                                                                  
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]                                                                                              
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                                                                                          
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge                                                                            
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport                                                                
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps                                                                  
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]                                                                                                          
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< pcl  No Makefile in package pcl                                                                                       
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> flann [ make ]                                                                                                        
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]                                                                                                      
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros                                                                                
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< flann ROS_NOBUILD in package flann                                                                                    
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rein [ make ]                                                                                                         
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rein [SKIP] No rule to make target None                                                                               
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> bigg_detector [ make ]                                                                                                
  [ rosmake ] Last 40 linesgg_detector: 3.1 sec ]                                                                     [ 1 Active 33/34 Complete ]
  {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Finding dependencies for /home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/cfg/BiGG.cfg
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    CMake Warning:
      Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
    
        CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
    
    
    -- Build files have been written to: /home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/build
    cd build && make -l4
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/build'
    make[2]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/build'
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/build'
    [ 33%] Built target ROSBUILD_gencfg_cpp
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/build'
    [ 33%] Built target rospack_gencfg
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/build'
    [ 33%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/build'
    [ 33%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/build'
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/build'
    [ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bigg_detector.dir/src/bigg.o
    /home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/src/bigg.cpp: In function ‘void {anonymous}::extractFeatures(const cv::Mat&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>&, cv::Mat&, const cv::Mat&)’:
    /home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/src/bigg.cpp:89:61: error: expected type-specifier
    /home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/src/bigg.cpp:89:61: error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘cv::DescriptorExtractor*’ in initialization
    /home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/src/bigg.cpp:89:61: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’
    make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/bigg_detector.dir/src/bigg.o] Error 1
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/build'
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/bigg_detector.dir/all] Error 2
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/build'
    make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector/build'
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
  [ rosmake ] Output from build of package bigg_detector written to:
  [ rosmake ]    /home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121008-104935/bigg_detector/build_output.log
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< bigg_detector [FAIL] [ 3.15 seconds ]                                                                                 
  [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package bigg_detector. 
  [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                               
  [ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                           
  [ rosmake ] Built 34 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                 
  [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                        
  [ rosmake ] /home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121008-104935                                                                              
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/recognition/bigg_detector$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45272/how-to-solve-%27cannot-convert-%E2%80%98int*%E2%80%99-to-%E2%80%98cv::descriptorextractor*%E2%80%99-in-initialization%27?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message "`expected type-specifier`" on the preceding line indicates that you have misspelled a type name or forgot to `#include` the appropriate header file where the type is defined. From this point on, the parser is thrown off the track, which means the error message about the `int` conversion is bogus and will disappear once you fix the original error. (It's probably some ancient C rule about converting unknown types to int by default.)

**Update:**
The offending line according to the posted sources (see comment below) is

```
static cv::DescriptorExtractor* descriptorExtractor = new cv::SiftDescriptorExtractor;
```

and the error message (line 89, column 61) points to the `cv::SiftDescriptorExtractor` part. On my system, this class is defined in the header
`<opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>`, which (as far as I can tell) is not included anywhere.

NB. This is not rocket science. All the information you needed was there, and I even pointed you in the right direction.

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2012-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-10-14**:
I'm not quite understand how to solve it? Thank you~

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2012-10-15**:
You solve it by correcting the spelling error. It is also possible that you forgot a semicolon ';' or a brace '}' somewhere before. Without the source code, I can't be more specific.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-10-26**:
Thank you~ Here is the source code. I'm still find somewhere to fix: svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_diamondback/stacks/object_recognition/bigg_detector

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-10-30**:
This package should work before, because it is released already. I'm not understand why workable package will also meet header missing problem. How to explain that?

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2012-10-30**:
Maybe it was written for a different ROS version with a different OpenCV version? There have been some significant changes around version 2.3

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-10-31**:
That connects a big problem. How you think such a great library doesn't support backward compatibility? Also ROS distribution also seems not support compatibility too. ex.eigen dependency problem.